# ErrorcaptureStackTrace(err) and cannot set headrs after they are sent to clients

Tags: express

I'm trying to create an  api using using node.js,postman,express.js,mongodb i came to final step of the project but i stuck at this point because of the error
"ErrorcaptureStackTrace(err); and cannot set headers after they are sent [This was the error I'm getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h0I27.png)to clients"

[This is my main body Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1f8MK.png)

i am expecting the solution

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

You got this error because you are sending a response two times. you have to remove the outer `res.send()` or simply you can use `try` and `catch` block and you don't need to use `.then()` and `.catch()`. you can use it like below.

```
app.post("students", (req, res) => {
  try {
    console.log(req.body)
    const user = new Strudent(req.body)
    user.save()
    res.status(201).send(user)
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(400).send(error.message)
  }
})
```